# How to filter noise in a 12v system introduced by an inverter?

Tags: dc, filter, noise, inverter, 12v

I have an RV with a 150 Ah battery bank and SureSine 300W 115V inverter. Due to space constraints, the inverter and the rest of the DC loads share about 6 ft length of wire to the batteries, but otherwise it’s a fairly typical setup.

The media center and speakers are running on the 12V and they pick up high pitched noise when the inverter is running, it gets worse the more AC loads I have.

The inverter probably already has bypass capacitors, but would it help if I added more? How do I choose the correct size? Would it help if I added a big ferrite bead on the positive rail going to the inverter? The peak current there is about 60A.

Also, does it make sense to filter the noise just at the media center as it uses a fraction of the power the inverter does?

Edit: I have a multimeter, but not much besides that to diagnose this.

Comment: How do you know there is noise with just a multimeter?

Comment: I can hear it with my ears on the speakers when the inverter is on.

Comment: Oh - you're talking about audio noise, not electrical noise? This could be due to vibrations, resonant frequencies between components, or some circuitry inside the inverter that you won't be able to access. Not sure if there is much you can do here besides filter caps as you've already self-suggested

Comment: Can you put a common mode choke around the cables and listen if that attenuated the noise?

Answer (score 3):

run   individual    leads  from the   batteries to the  inverter  use   shielded cables   ground   the shields      run these in   metallic   conduit   ground  the conduit   put some large  capacitors in   parallel   with the inverter  dc   feed   and  finaly   if needed    put the  inverter in a   Faraday cage a copper   enclosure   and  ground   this

Answer (score 2):

Your setup is similar to car audio so I would imagine they have a suitable solution to this problem. You can buy very large audio capacitors in the multiple farad range. Place one of these as close to the audio system as possible and see if that resolves your problem. If not you can put an inductor in front of this capacitor to create an LC filter.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be caused by a ground loop. I had mistakenly made two connections to the chassis when installing the inverter, one at the battery and another near the inverter. This caused the aluminum frame of the camper pick up quite a bit of EMI. There's still some noise so I'll try some of the suggestions here, but it's a tiny fraction of what it was.